# Undo a weakened statement in sequent calculus later in the inferences

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, proof-theory, formal-proofs, sequent-calculus

I'm working on an answer to (b) of Mathematical Logic, Ebbinghaus et. al. 1984 p. 64

Consider the following inference:
$$
\frac{\begin{align}\Gamma \vdash A\\ \Gamma \vdash B\end{align}}{\Gamma \vdash A\land B}
$$
I show it is a valid inference, the question only allowing a restricted set of rules, using Weakening, Contraposition, and the $\lor$-Antecedent rules. But I'm stuck on the last part:

$Γ\vdash A$

$Γ\vdash B$

$Γ \, \neg C \vdash A$

$Γ \, \neg C \vdash B$

$Γ \, \neg A \vdash C$

$Γ \, \neg B \vdash C$

$Γ \, (\neg A\lor \neg B) \vdash C$

$Γ \, \neg C \vdash \neg(\neg A\lor\neg B)$

How would I get rid of the $\neg C$ I acquired from weakening? I have access to explosion, Contraposition, Modus ponens, and these (the last formula on each line is made true by the ones before it):
[image]
I also have
$$
\frac{\begin{align}\Gamma \vdash \phi\\ \Gamma \phi \vdash \psi \end{align}}{\Gamma \vdash \psi}
$$

Comment: Is the list of rules you provided complete? For instance, can you use de Morgan's laws? They're not listed, but you use it in your last step.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I wouldn't be surprised at all if Ebbinghaus defined $\wedge$ as a derived connective using $\vee$ and $\neg$.

Comment: Yep, $\land$ is not primitive, and the rules listed are all those available (except the quantification rules). The last line relies on defining $A\land B$ as $\neg(\neg A \lor \neg B)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the same proof using $\neg C$ in place of $C$, concluding $\Gamma, \neg \neg C \vdash A \land B$. Together with the original proof of $\Gamma, \neg C \vdash A \land B$, we can use the rule `PC` to eliminate $C$ entirely and conclude $\Gamma \vdash A \land B$.

$C$ seems to just be a placeholder which is needed to apply some of the rules. So there really isn't much that changes in the proof if we replace $C$ by something else.

Comment: I fixed a mistake: the proof ends without $A \land B$, staying at $\neg(\neg A \lor \neg B)$, since it wasn't available. I don't think we can use this approach in that case, no?

Comment: @shintuku Are you saying you weren't able to prove $\Gamma, \neg C \vdash A \land B$? What is the exact definition of $A \land B$?

Comment: In this case, it is $\neg ( \neg A \lor \neg B)$ (and this, without $\neg C$, is what we want). But I'm not seeing how we can apply PC in this case, given that we would only have, upon following your instructions $\Gamma C \vdash \neg(\neg A \lor \neg B)$. I may very well be misunderstanding your comment however

Comment: If $A \land B$ equals $\neg (\neg A \lor \neg B)$ *by definition* then it doesn't matter which one you have. In any case, my answer suffices to eliminate C. In `PC`, $\varphi$ would just have to be $\neg (\neg A \lor \neg B)$ (and $\psi$ would be $\neg C$).

Comment: $$
\frac{\begin{align}\Gamma C \vdash \neg ( \neg A \lor \neg B)\\ \Gamma \neg C \vdash \neg(\neg A \lor \neg B) \end{align}}{\Gamma \vdash \neg ( \neg A \lor \neg B)}
$$
If I understand you correctly, we would be getting the above, but supposing we begin using $\neg C$ instead of $C$, where would you get the second line in order to perform PC? Truly sorry if I'm misunderstanding you

Comment: Unless I'm misreading, the second line is the conclusion of your proof (from the question), right? One small correction though. We want to have $\Gamma, \neg \neg C \vdash \neg (\neg A \lor \neg B)$ on the first line (unless you want to do the extra work of eliminating the double negative). [didn't see your edit till now] You want to perform the proof in your question *twice* - once with $C$ and once with $\neg C$. The first time we get the second line. The second time we get the first line (with $\neg \neg C$ in place of $C$).

Comment: Oh, you are right, it is $\Gamma \neg \neg C$ on the first line, thank you. On the second line: that is indeed what I conclude with, but wouldn't it be unavailable if we begin with $\neg C$ instead of $C$? Since I obtain it with contraposition from 
$Γ(\neg A\lor \neg B) \vdash C$

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for the clarification, I finally understood! Thank you very much for taking the time!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128197/discussion-between-s-c-and-shintuku).